# Conditional distribution for 3 variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis

[image]

Everywhere it is done for bivariate or given a hints. But Not in details for trivariate.

Comment: The second part of this question is a strong hint: because $Y$ is multivariate Normal, the regression of $Y_1$ on $(Y_2,Y_3)$ is linear and its coefficients are determined by $\Sigma.$  The linear regression determines the conditional distribution.

Comment: I can't understand your answer.  Is it possible to solve this problem? @whuber